# Como criar uma função para remover caracteres indesejados, anti injection

Tags: python

Olá, eu pesquisei na internet quais caracteres remover, mas as buscas não me responderam a dúvida..
Então, eu procurei sei sobre anti-sqlinjection no python, mas não encontrei nenhuma forma de fazer isso removendo diretamente os caracteres ao formar a string... Só encontrei solucoes do tipo estáticas, onde vc ja forma o comando executando, pra mim esse tipo não serve, porque eu tenho formas dinâmicas de pegar os resultados, dependendo do resultado tal.

Preciso que a variavel se forme da seguinte forma por exemplo:

```
senha=d[6:]
con=consultarSql()
if senha!="":
    sql="SELECT id FROM motorista WHERE senha="+"'"+antisql(senha)+"'"
    myresult=con.consultar(sql)
```

Por enquanto o único caractere que estou removendo é um tab, porque ele tava atrapalhando

Seria tipo assim:

```
def antisql(string):
    string=string.replace(" ","")
    string=string.replace("'","")
    string=string.replace("\"","")
    string=string.replace("\\","")
    ....aqui da replace nas outras caracteres
```

O que preciso é de uma lista completa de caracteres que possam a vir me dar problemas. -> Só para constar meu software a parte do python é um websocket, e ele dá um resultado json, por isso eu removi esse caractere de espaço maior <- nao é o espaço normal não, é um caractere de espaço maior, que buga o json..

Comment: Deve existir algo pronto e que funcionará bem melhor que o seu.

Comment: Isto já está implementado nos _drivers_ dos bancos de dados, consulte http://bobby-tables.com/python para maiores detalhes.

Comment: Eu ja vi esses métodos, mas eu já disse, eu preciso fazer isso de forma dinâmica, dependendo da informação o resultado é um ou outro.... Não quero implementar a segurança direto na execução do sql, quero proteger a variavel antes mesmo de criar a string sql

Comment: Eu já tentei fazer dessas formas mas não deu certo, eu criei uma classe pra conectar no mysql, e fazer as consultas e/ou executar, é mais facil mandar a string sql pronta, do que mandar as tabelas e dados pra def.

Comment: Se é dinâmica e esses métodos não satisfazem suas necessidades, precisaremos que você cite **todos** os casos possíveis de acontecer na aplicação, bem como listar todos os requisitos a serem satisfeitos. Sem isso, qualquer resposta será baseada em especulação, sem trazer qualquer benefício a comunidade. Já adianto que fazer replace de caracteres não adiciona nenhum tipo de segurança à aplicação. Dito isso, votei para fechar a  pergunta como não clara até todos os detalhes serem apresentados.

Comment: Então, um problema que estou tendo no momento é quanto ao parentesis, tento fazer algo assim SELECT id FROM cliente WHERE telefone='(xx)xxxxxxxxx' AND senha='senhadapessoa' Não esta executando no python, quando faço a busca no phpmyadmin funciona normal, mas no python nao retorna nenhuma resultado, será que parentesis nao pode?

Answer (score -1):

```
remove = set(";:,.'")
def clean(sentence):
    for c in set(sentence)&remove:
        sentence = sentence.replace(c,"")
    return sentence

Sentence = "feijão 'com, arroz"


CleanSentence = clean(Sentence)

print(Sentence)
print(CleanSentence)
```

Comment: Você pode utilizar também 

      conn.escape_string()